# How to give row a background in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `row` and `column` inside a `container` in Bootstrap 3 grid.
The problem is, what is the correct syntax to give row a background without left and right padding ?

See the example here:
[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5WS32/)

Comment: Are you trying to remove that space??

Answer (score 0):

Container class add left and right padding/margin.
Do not use container.

```
<div class="row">
    <img src="http://alphawolves.net/dev/vesna/image/slider01.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p><- - why is this space here and on the right side ? </p>            
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5WS32/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css, and it should do the trick

```
.container {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}
```